# How do I read the "using module" statements in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1, powershell-module

Powershell 5 has a nice declarative "using module" statement that can be provided at the top of a file to declare the dependencies of the script.  Presumably one should be able to use this programmatically to determine what the dependencies of a given powershell script or module are.  But I can't find anything on how to consume that - does only powershell use that internally?  Is there no developer-API to read the requirements-list of a .ps1 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [your own effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76814726/45375) with some **background information**:

**Preface**:

- The following finds [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using) in a given script file (`*.ps1`), which not only comprises `using module` statements, but also `using assembly` and `using namespace` statements; `using namespace` statements latter do not constitute a dependency per se, as their only purpose is to allow to refer to types by simple name only.
- `using` statements are not the *only* way to import modules and load assemblies (e.g, the former can also be imported with `Import-Module`, and the latter with `Add-Type`). Additionally, there are potentially *implicit* module dependencies that rely on [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading).

In short: **Static analysis via `using` statements isn't guaranteed to find all dependencies**.

---

- Ultimately, it is PowerShell's language parser, [`[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser) that provides the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) that your solution relies on.
- It has a static [`::ParseFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser.ParseFile) method that directly accepts script file paths.

  - However, as with any .NET method call, a *full path* must be passed, given that .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's.
- The `.UsingStatement` property of the [`[System.Management.Automation.Language.ScriptBlockAst]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.ScriptBlockAst) instance returned by `::ParseFile()` (and as contained in a [`[scriptblock]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock)'s `.Ast` property, as shown in your answer) contains [`[System.Management.Automation.Language.UsingStatementAst]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.UsingStatementAst) instances, if any, describing the `using` statements.

  - Indeed, their `.Name` property is filled in for `using module` statements with simple module *names and paths* as well as for the assembly names and paths used in `using assembly` statements.

    - `.Name` isn't a *string*, but an instance of [`[System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst). While such an instance by definition has only *verbatim* content - variables cannot be used in `using` statements - it may contain incidental *quoting* or *escaping*, because `using module Foo` may also be expressed as `using module 'Foo'` or `using module "Foo"`.
    - Removing the incidental quoting can be as simple as `` .Name.ToString.Trim("'`"") ``, though, at least hypothetically, this isn't fully robust, because it would fail with something like `using module 'Foo''Bar'`. Even an *unquoted* form that uses `` ` ``-escaping could fail, e.g. `` using module Foo`'Bar ``. A pragmatic solution is to use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) on `.Name.ToString()` passed to `Write-Output` - while `Invoke-Expression` is [generally to be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression), its use is safe here. Note that passing an argument that isn't a string to `Invoke-Expression` implicitly stringifies it.
  - Only `using module` statements that use a FQMN ([Fully Qualified Module Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module#-fullyqualifiedname), e.g.
    `using module @{ ModuleName = 'Foo'; ModuleVersion = '2.0.1' }`)
    have the `.ModuleSpecification` property filled in instead, in the form of a [`[System.Management.Automation.Language.HashtableAst]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.HashtableAst) instance.

    - Reconstructing a [`[hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) from this instance is non-trivial, but, given that its `.ToString()` representation is the original hash-table literal *source code* (also composed of *literal* values only), the simplest approach is the simplest approach is again to pass its string representation to `Invoke-Expression`.

The following puts it all together:

- It extracts all `using module` and `using assembly` statements from a given script file (`*.ps1`) ...
- ... and outputs a `[pscustomobject]` instance for each with three properties:

  - `.Kind` is either `Module` or `Assembly` (passing the `.UsingStatementKind` property value through)
  - `.NameOrSpec` is:

    - either: the module or assembly name or path, with incidental quoting and escaping removed

      - **Note**: Any *relative* path is relative *to the script's location*.
    - or: a `[hashtable]` instance representing the FQMN in the originating `using module` statement.
  - `.SourceCode` is the original statement *as text* (`[string]`).

```bash
$scriptPath = './test.ps1'
[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile(
  (Convert-Path $scriptPath), 
  [ref] $null, # `out` parameter that receives the array of tokens; not used here
  [ref] $null # `out` parameter that receives an array of errors, if any; not used here.
).UsingStatements | 
  Where-Object UsingStatementKind -ne Namespace | # Filter out `using namespace` statements
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Kind       = $_.UsingStatementKind
      NameOrSpec = if ($_.ModuleSpecification) { 
                     Invoke-Expression $_.ModuleSpecification 
                   } else { 
                     Invoke-Expression ('Write-Output ' + $_.Name)
                   }
      SourceCode = $_.Extent
    }
  }
```

If you fill `test.ps1` with the following content...

```bash
using module PSReadLine
# Variations with quoting
using module 'PSReadLine'
using module "PSReadLine"

# Module with escaped embedded '
using module Foo`'Bar

# FQMN module spec
using module @{ ModuleName = 'Foo'; ModuleVersion = '2.0.0' }

# Reference to built-in assembly.
# Note: Broken in PowerShell (Core) as of v7.3.6 - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11856
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
# Variation with quoting
using assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'

# Reference to assembly relative to the script's location.
using assembly ./path/to/some/assembly.dll
# Variation with quoting
using assembly './path/to/some/assembly.dll'

# ...
```

... then running the code above yields the following:

```
    Kind NameOrSpec                                  SourceCode
    ---- ----------                                  ----------
  Module PSReadLine                                  using module PSReadLine
  Module PSReadLine                                  using module 'PSReadLine'
  Module PSReadLine                                  using module "PSReadLine"
  Module Foo'Bar                                     using module Foo`'Bar
  Module {[ModuleName, Foo], [ModuleVersion, 2.0.0]} using module @{ ModuleName = 'Foo'; ModuleVersion = '2.0.0' }
Assembly System.Windows.Forms                        using assembly System.Windows.Forms
Assembly System.Windows.Forms                        using assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'
Assembly ./path/to/some/assembly.dll                 using assembly ./path/to/some/assembly.dll
Assembly ./path/to/some/assembly.dll                 using assembly './path/to/some/assembly.dll'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some help on Mastodon from [@nyanhp](https://mastodon.social/@nyanhp@metalhead.club/110706783680954819), I have the answer - the "ScriptBlock" class.

```
$ScriptBlock = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content $scriptPath -Raw))
$ScriptBlock.Ast.UsingStatements | 
    Select-Object Alias, Extent, ModuleSpecification, Name, UsingStatementKind
```

yields

```
Alias               :
Extent              : using module  ActiveDirectory
ModuleSpecification :
Name                : ActiveDirectory
UsingStatementKind  : Module
```

which is a good place to start for getting more details.  I assume that if a  full module spec is provided instead of a simple name, it will appear in the `ModuleSpecification` member instead of the `Name` member.